# Import fusion chart trial version into Adobe Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, fusioncharts

I have installed Adobe Flash Builder and also downloaded the trial version of fusion chart on my windows PC. How do I import the fusion chart into the Flash Builder?

Comment: I'm torn as to whether this should be closed or not; as it seems like direct product support that would be better asked for FusionCharts.  I assume FusionCharts is distributed as a SWC and you just need to add the SWC to your project.

Answer (score 0):

For use in Flash Builder to build ActionScript 3 based projects, you need a specialised product named - [FusionCharts for Flex](http://www.fusioncharts.com/extensions/adobe-flex/).

[FusionCharts for Flex documentation](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/flex/charts/) lets you know how to [install](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/flex/charts/Contents/installation_types_flashBuilder4.html).